# Connect neighbor vertices into a polygons? Geometry nodes 3.x

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to connect vertices (separate points) into a mesh grid inside the geometry nodes? What I basically need is to get this: [image]

from this: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this example will help you *(Blender 3.1.2)*:

[image: Connect neighbor vertices into a polygons - Screen 1]

[image: Connect neighbor vertices into a polygons - Screen 2]

- Here I simply instantiate mesh lines at the points, extrude them minimally in height so that I get edges from them.
- I merge these with the node `Mesh Boolean` with the underlying grid (you can also do this with a convex hull).
- The resulting mesh is then simply triangulated and the outer hull is removed again.
- To make the positions exactly match the points, I get them directly back from the points and merge identical vertices.
- In the last step I extrude the mesh again, and separate the edges. You can omit this step if you don't need the edges individually.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very useful!