# Blender Geometry Nodes - Create individual XYZ curve/mesh lines per edge-defined cubic area

Tags: geometry-nodes

How could XYZ curve/mesh lines be created for each cubic area as defined by the object's edges?

[image]

It seems that this would be theoretically possible, assuming there is a way to connect the points created from the original edges, and then repeat that once more from the resulting edges to get the above pictured result.

[image]

[This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251202/connect-neighbor-vertices-into-a-polygons-geometry-nodes-3-x) seemed like a decent start, but the desired result was still out of reach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This setup here might be of interest to you:

[image]

Here I first capture the inverted normals so that they point inward.

Then I convert the faces into points and instantiate curves there.

At the same time, I move the positions of the faces a little inward, so that I can apply them to the original geometry as a starting position for a raycast to the opposite faces.

This *Hit Position*, which is then the position of the opposite face in this specific case, I transfer to the endpoint of the curve.

You can then process the curves further at the end and, for example, turn them into a mesh with `Curve to Mesh`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>